# Tensorflowjs - optimize.minimize cannot find a connection between any variable and the resulr of the loss function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to adapt Daniel Shiffman's linear regression exemple with tensorflowjs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZR-N_dhK2M) to use a polynomial equation instead of a linear equation. But I am struggling with the predict function.
In my first version (see below), the optimize.minimze function does not find a link between my function and my tf.variables (that are stored in my coefficients array). 
On the other hand, my second version works, but have a memory leak that I have not been able to fix

Here's the non-working version :

```js
const WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 400;

const x_vals = [];
const y_vals = [];

let coefficients = [];
let degree = 5;

let lr = 0.2;
let optimizer = tf.train.adamax(lr);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  background(0);
  initCoeffs();

  let up = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < WIDTH; i += WIDTH / 10) {
    x_vals.push(map(i, 0, WIDTH, -1, 1));
    y_vals.push(map((up) ? 0 : HEIGHT, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1));
    up = !up;
  }
}

function initCoeffs() {
  for (let i = 0; i < degree; i++)
    coefficients.push(tf.variable(tf.scalar(random(1))));
}

function loss(pred, labels) {
  return tf.losses.meanSquaredError(labels, pred);
}

function predict(x) {
  const xs = tf.tensor1d(x);
  const ys = tf.variable(tf.zerosLike(xs));
  for (let i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    const coef = coefficients[i];
    const pow_ts = tf.fill(xs.shape, degree - i);
    const sum = tf.add(ys, coef.mul(xs.pow(pow_ts)));
    ys.assign(sum);
  }
  ys.print();
  return ys;
}

function draw() {
  noFill();
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(8);
  for (let i = 0; i < x_vals.length; i++) {
    point(map(x_vals[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(y_vals[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  }
  strokeWeight(4);

  if (x_vals.length > 0) {
    tf.tidy(() => {
      const ys = tf.tensor1d(y_vals);
      optimizer.minimize(() => loss(predict(x_vals), ys));
    });
  }


  let lineX = [];
  for (let x = -1.1; x <= 1.1; x += 0.01)
    lineX.push(x);
  const ys = tf.tidy(() => predict(lineX));
  let lineY = ys.dataSync();
  ys.dispose();

  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++)
    curveVertex(map(lineX[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(lineY[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  endShape();

  for (let i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++) {
    stroke(200, 100, 100);
    point(map(lineX[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(lineY[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  x_vals.push(map(mouseX, 0, WIDTH, -1, 1));
  y_vals.push(map(mouseY, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.11.2/tf.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I have this error in console :

> Cannot find a connection between any variable and the result of the loss function y=f(x). Please make sure the operations that use variables are inside the function f passed to minimize().

But if I change my predict function like this, it works :

```
function predict(x) {
  const xs = tf.tensor1d(x);
  let ys = tf.variable(tf.zerosLike(xs));
  for (let i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    const coef = coefficients[i];
    const pow_ts = tf.fill(xs.shape, degree - i);
    const sum = tf.add(ys, coef.mul(xs.pow(pow_ts)));
    ys = sum;
  }
  ys.print();
  return ys;
}
```

The problem is that this second version creates a memory leak as I use let to declare my ys tf.variable.

How can I fix my code to avoid a memory leak, without having the optimize.minimizer error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get my code to work without memory leak by manually disposing ys variable before assigning it to the result of the tf.add function.

Here's my working solution

```js
const WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 400;

const x_vals = [];
const y_vals = [];

let coefficients = [];
let degree = 15;

let lr = 0.2;
let optimizer = tf.train.adamax(lr);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  background(0);
  initCoeffs();

  let up = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < WIDTH; i += WIDTH / 10) {
    x_vals.push(map(i, 0, WIDTH, -1, 1));
    y_vals.push(map((up) ? 0 : HEIGHT, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1));
    up = !up;
  }
}

function initCoeffs() {
  for (let i = 0; i < degree; i++)
    coefficients.push(tf.variable(tf.scalar(random(1))));
}

function loss(pred, labels) {
  return tf.losses.meanSquaredError(labels, pred);
}

function predict(x) {
  const xs = tf.tensor1d(x);
  let ys = tf.variable(tf.zerosLike(xs));
  for (let i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    const coef = coefficients[i];
    const pow_ts = tf.fill(xs.shape, degree - i);
    const sum = tf.add(ys, coefficients[i].mul(xs.pow(pow_ts)));
    ys.dispose();
    ys = sum.clone();
  }
  return ys;
}

function draw() {
  noFill();
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(8);
  for (let i = 0; i < x_vals.length; i++) {
    point(map(x_vals[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(y_vals[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  }
  strokeWeight(4);

  if (x_vals.length > 0) {
    tf.tidy(() => {
      const ys = tf.tensor1d(y_vals);
      optimizer.minimize(() => loss(predict(x_vals), ys), coefficients);
    });
  }


  let lineX = [];
  for (let x = -1.1; x <= 1.1; x += 0.01)
    lineX.push(x);
  const ys = tf.tidy(() => predict(lineX));
  let lineY = ys.dataSync();
  ys.dispose();

  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++)
    curveVertex(map(lineX[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(lineY[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  endShape();

  for (let i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++) {
    stroke(200, 100, 100);
    point(map(lineX[i], -1, 1, 0, WIDTH), map(lineY[i], -1, 1, 0, HEIGHT));
  }
  //console.log(tf.memory().numTensors);
}

function mousePressed() {
  x_vals.push(map(mouseX, 0, WIDTH, -1, 1));
  y_vals.push(map(mouseY, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.11.2/tf.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if those are bugs :

- using ys = tf.add() creates a new tensor that is not disposed by tidy()
- using ys.assign(tf.add()) prevents optimizer.minimize() function to find relation with variables